# Starting expmple for partial reconfiguration on Zybo board

Tags: partial, xilinx, vivado

I am going to learn working with partial reconfiguration on Zybo board. I know how to use vivado IDE but for starting I need some tutorial with implemented example related to DPR. Is there any simple tutorial for the beginning? steps for making partial reconfiguration project is written in xilinx user guide(ug720) but no such example is given. Please help!

Comment: I also want to implement a simple PR example on Zybo. If you have found something regarding PR tutorial; please let me know at my email: smzk2001@gmail.com